# What is the right way to automount drives for selected users using /etc/fstab?

Tags: partitioning, mount, fstab, automount

I am currently mounting my ntfs drive using

```
UUID=123FSDF345233 /media/user/Disk ntfs uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000,sync,auto,rw 0 0
UUID=123FSDF345233 /media/user/Disk ntfs uid=1001,gid=1002,umask=000,sync,auto,rw 0 0
```

in `/etc/fstab` for selected number of users.  I found this method while experimenting with `/etc/fstab`. Is this the right way to do this or is there any other better method to do it?

Something like this

```
UUID=123FSDF345233 /media/user/Disk ntfs uid=[1000,1001],gid=[1000,1002],umask=000,sync,auto,rw 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
man mount
...[bla]
Mount options for ntfs
...[blub]
uid=value, gid=value and umask=value
 Set the file permission on the filesystem.
 The umask value is given in octal.
 By default, the files are owned by root and not readable by somebody else.
```

I can't see any valid option to bundle user or group ids.

It's a good choice maybe to *group* your *users* and give this group access by using *gid=value*.